Vaadin TreeGrid: overlapping components when scrolling
I recently migrated from Vaadin 14 to Vaadin 24. Previously, I had a perfectly working TreeGrid which consisted of a single ComponentColumn rendering custom elements. However, since the migration it seems I consistently get visual glitches when scrolling through the grid in the form of overlapping components:

These visual glitches do resolve themselves when I continue to scroll further and then scroll back:

Any ideas what might cause this and what I could do to resolve it?
Kind regards

Have you update to the latest Vaadin 24.5 version. Moreover this kind of issues should be reported to Vaadin's bug tracker. Please include code to reproduce the problem. https://github.com/vaadin/web-components
